# Why is this function not incrementing my variable in c?

Tags: c, function, pointers, printing, increment

So just experimenting with pointers in C.

```
void inc(int *p){
    ++(*p);
}

int main(){
    int x = 0;
    int *p;
    *p = x;
    inc(p);
    printf("x = %i",x);
}
```

Why is this printing "x = 0" instead of "x = 1"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's your error:

```
*p = x;
```

You're dereferencing `p`, which is unassigned, and giving it the current value of `x`.  So `x` isn't changed because you didn't pass a pointer to `x` to your function, and dereferencing an uninitialized pointer invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You instead want to assign the *address of* `x` to `p`:

```
p = &x;
```

Alternately, you can remove `p` entirely and just pass the address of `x` to `inc`:

```
inc(&x);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you don't set `p` to the address of `x`

Use

```
p = &x;
```

instead of

```
*p = x;
```

With `*p = x` you cause undefined behaviour because `p` has indeterminate value and points *somewhere*. But you don't know where it points and with `*p = x` you write the value of `x` to that memory location.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the address of x to p. As mentioned in the other answers you might just want to pass in `inc(&x);`. No need to declare a variable and waste it like that.